# Oracle PL/SQL: a scheduled procedure, leading to firing of a trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Okay, I'm new to Oracle PL/SQL and I've stumbled across a problem that I cannot figure out. 
I have a procedure that leads to transferring data from one table to another and a trigger that activates on the insertion in the second table. I scheduled that procedure to run every minute (for testing - would be daily once I've figured it out), using the **DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT**  - the scheduled part works perfectly, however after the completion of the procedure the trigger is not fired. I tried with before and after insert clauses, but it is still not working. If I call the procedure directly it works and it does fire the trigger just fine. So... I'm already wondering whether the scheduled procedure can fire the trigger at all?!

This is the schedule's code:

```
DECLARE
  VJOBN BINARY_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
  JOB => VJOBN,
  INTERVAL => 'SYSDATE + 1/2880', 
  WHAT => 'BEGIN my_procedure(); END;'
  );
END;


create or replace TRIGGER TO_PRJ
AFTER INSERT ON PROJECTS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING
  THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTED PROJECT WITH ID:  '||:NEW.PROJECT_ID||')
  END IF;
END;​
```

Table PROJECTS has ID number, name varchar2, and some other that are not important.
The procedure transfers the ID and the name from orders to projects.

P.S. I'm using http://apex.oracle.com and when I get the timestamp from it the time is actually 6 hours behind me - not sure if it can be of any significance...

Comment: Oracle jobs will do as usual process. Don't need to worry about trigger. If you set trigger in your stored procedure or table, it will run as usual. By the way, why you put "Being and End" in What clause?

Comment: @ppshein Well... I am worrying about the trigger, because it doesn't run when the job calls the stored procedure. And I put the being end thing because that's how I saw it on one of the tutorials that I've read - no longer remember which one, searched a billion while trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBMS_OUTPUT` and `DBMS_JOB` do not work the way you are trying to use them. The scheduled job is probably running, the trigger is firing - but since `DBMS_OUTPUT`needs to be activated in the session that executes the `DBMS_OUTPUT` commands (i.e. the internal session used by `DBMS_JOB`) you will never see any output.

`DBMS_OUTPUT`'s output is not visible across session, so the session that issues the `DBMS_JOB.submit` command will NOT receive the output, even if `DBMS_OUTPUT` is activated for that session.

Comment: Yeah, I just read about it and realized what is going on. But is there a way the scheduled job working with the trigger to output a message?

Comment: You could e.g. use a table for communication, or UTL_FILE to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scheduler, it's much better then jobs. And bring there code of trigger and tables, it may help

Comment: I tried with scheduler as well - the procedure executes, but the trigger doesn't fire. I updated the first post with the trigger code.

Comment: there are ways to send messages from scheduler, i never used it but they exist. If you need messages, why can't u use special table and insert data there?